# gtag.js user id: config vs. set

Tags: google-analytics

This pertains to setting user id in google analytics calls, using gtag.

1.) The docs say to set user id this way:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID', {
  'user_id': 'USER_ID'
});
```

(ref: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cookies-user-id)

2.) But when actually setting up user id functionality in the analytics console, the notes there say to set user-id this way:

```
gtag('set', {'user_id': 'USER_ID'}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.

// The value must be set for all hits in the session. We recommend using the set method to ensure all additional Analytics hits on the page contain this value.
```

So...which is best, and why? Thanks!

Comment: where is the ref for 2 point. Please share

Answer (score 8):

this depends on your particular goals. if you know the user id for any particular user form the start of the session you might use `gtag( 'config','GA_MEASUREMENT_ID','user_id': 'USER_ID' });`
If the flow is the same for authenticated and non-authentificated users you might use `gtag( 'config','GA_MEASUREMENT_ID')` followed by some `gtag( 'send' ...)` and conditionally call `gtag('set', {'user_id': 'USER_ID'});` in between.

the key difference is that `gtag('set', )` updates the existing tracking data and `gtag('config' ...)` creates the tracker itself and sends a pageview hit if not opted out.

Comment: Thanks, but could you clarify what you mean by "If the flow is the same for authenticated and non-authentificated users you might use..."

Comment: Could you please elaborate and improve this answer?